# Objective C: Access #define by stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to access #defines by stringWithFormat, e. g. inside a loop?

For example:

```
#define text1 @"AAA"
#define text2 @"BBB"
#define text3 @"CCC"
...
```

And the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text%i",i]); //want to access #defines here
}
```

Comment: No. `#define` is only used ay compile time, not runtime.

Comment: Is it mandatory to define strings like that? may be you can store them in array instead?

Comment: What languages have you used before?  If you've programmed in C/C++ you should understand that you can't do this.  If only Java then maybe you can be excused.

Comment: It's impossible with `stringWithFormat`, but it's possible with using other macro which iterates over defines in compiletime. Sorry it's too complicated, can't provide it's code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` can be accessed only `NSLog(@"%@", text1);`

your `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text%i",i]` will produce text1 string not variable.
,
to accomplish desired task, you 'd better to use array:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"AAA", @"BBB", @"CCC"];
NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]);
```